# PHP: Check if string is URL

Tags: php, validation, url, native

I`m trying to get all the css code from a website , I have difficuties trying to determine whether the href is realtive or absolute.I was using filter_var() , but it does not  properly with urls starting with //.

```
<?php 
        $file = file_get_contents($url);

        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadHTML($file);

        $domcss = $doc->getElementsByTagName('link');  //Get all .css file
        foreach($domcss as $links) {
            if( strtolower($links->getAttribute('rel')) == "stylesheet" ) {
                $href  =  $links->getAttribute('href');

                if(filter_var($href, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){ //Check if href is relative or absolute ,not working correctly
                    $css = file_get_contents($href);
                }else{
                    $css = file_get_contents($this->url.$href);
                }

                //echo $css;

            }
        }
```

For example:

```
var_dump(filter_var('//google.bg' , FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)); //false
```

Comment: @AntoineB `//` is a protocol-less URL. It tells the browser to use whatever protocol the main page used (http or https)

Comment: This is a known "bug" and has been reported before: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72301